# Packaging Multiple application together in ClickOnce deployment

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, deployment, clickonce

I have a requirement of publishing three different applications( WPF - *exe) using ClickOnce deployment approach. This is very much similar to the MS Office suite where we have multiple office application which gets installed in one go. Do anyone know the ways to achieve this using VS 2012

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use ClickOnce, you have to publish the applications separately, and the user has to install the applications separately (but you can group them together on the user's Start menu). Otherwise you want to look into WiX or InstallShield or some other product.

To get them to group together on the Start menu, set the Publisher name and Suite name to the same values, and set the Product Name to the name of the application.

For example, if you set the Publisher Name to Contoso and the Suite name to FunWithClickOnce, you will see an entry on the start menu for Contoso, and under it you will see the suite "FunWithClickOnce", and under that you will see the application.

Note that if you leave the suite name blank, it will just put the applications under the start folder for the publisher name.